# Detect finger X and Y positions when touching and releasing screen over html file in IE11

Tags: html, swipe

How can I get X and Y position of my finger when I swipe over html file in IE 11. I want to check if I want to move left or right. How can I detect that in JavaScript over html in IE 11 ?

Comment: clientX and clientY have u used that ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_event_clientxy
just check dis link

Comment: Yes I did try clientX and clientY. But they do return the values where the user clicks. I need to click then move cursor. After moving the cursor I want to determine if user was moving left or right